# W3 Cache Hiding Shipping Zones

Tags: wordpress, caching, pagespeed

Good evening,
In the past, once a week I have noticed that the W3 Cache Plugin has consistently Hidden the  Shipping Zones in the WordPress admin dashboard

Is there a reason for this or are the developers working to resolve this issue?